# Enable mod_php for apache when provisioning Vagrant with Puppet

Tags: puppet

I have a Vagrant machine provisioned by Puppet. I was able to install PHP & Apache but mod_php is not enabled so I can't run PHP scripts. I am using [puppetlabs/apache](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache).

```
include apache::mod::php
```

does not work for me as it tries to yum install php. My package name is php56w though so for obvious reasons it ends up in conflicts and does not install. I could see in php.pp manifest that this class has a parameter $package_name but I could not get anywhere with changing its default value.

Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution straight after posting this question. The answer is in the docs - https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache#class-apachemodphp

> Overriding the package name:

```
class {'::apache::mod::php':
  package_name => "php54-php",
  path         => "${::apache::params::lib_path}/libphp54-php5.so",
}
```